# How I can don't change some column under certain conditions via an SQL statement which can bind parameters

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE "table" (
"id"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
"col1" BLOB,
"col2" BLOB,
"col3" BLOB,
"coln" BLOB
);

id|col1|col2|col3|coln
1 | 1-1| 1-2| 1-3| 1-n
2 | 2-1| 2-2| 2-3| 2-n

UPDATE table SET col1=?, col2=?, col3=?, coln=? WHERE id=?;
```

How I can don't change some column under certain conditions just via the above SQL statement.

sqlite.

for example,

```
public static class Bean{
    public long id;
    public byte[] col1;
    public byte[] col2;
    public byte[] col3;
    public byte[] coln;
}

PreparedStatement psUpdate = dsConn.prepareStatement("UPDATE table SET col1=?, col2=?, col3=?, coln=? WHERE id=?;");
Bean bean = new Bean();
if(null != bean.col1){
    psUpdate.setBytes(1, bean.col1);//col1
}else{
    psUpdate.omitColumn(1);//omit to update
}
if(null != bean.col2){
    psUpdate.setBytes(2, bean.col2);//col2
}else{
    psUpdate.omitColumn(2);//omit to update
}
if(null != bean.col3){
    psUpdate.setBytes(3, bean.col3);//col3
}else{
    psUpdate.omitColumn(3);//omit to update
}
if(null != bean.coln){
    psUpdate.setBytes(4, bean.coln);//coln
}else{
    psUpdate.omitColumn(4);//omit to update
}
psUpdate.setBytes(5, bean.id);//WHERE id=?
psUpdate.executeUpdate();
```

I haved read the document about sqlite or java. Unfortunately, it seems imposible.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: `can dont change` sound weird, isnt clear what are you asking. What condition are those? and which column you want update or not? can you provide a detail example?

Comment: [Dynamic SQL](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/myth-directory/dynamic-sql-is-slow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just construct the appropriate UPDATE statement with only the columns that you actually want to update.

But if you really want to use a single statement, you could use [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) to update the columns with their old value if the parameter is NULL:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET col1 = CASE WHEN ?1 IS NULL THEN col1 ELSE ?1 END,
    col2 = CASE WHEN ?2 IS NULL THEN col2 ELSE ?2 END,
    ...
WHERE id = ?5;
```

Comment: It is probably not good practice for the idea just using a single statement, but I just want it. `SET column-name=expr` from  [UPDATE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).     [Core Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html), **ifnull(X,Y)** shrink the code, but will return a copy.